# API Requires Query paramters and Body

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, retrofit2

[image: See Rest Client Screenshot] How to use query paramters and Body at the same time. Query paramters are used in GET and we append in URL. and in post we submit Body. but this API required both.

```
 URL  = http://www.MYWEBSITENAME.com/api/serveVideos/serveVideosToClient.php

 QUERY  PARAMS = show_by=rating&start=1&end=10
 HEADER  = X-WWW-FORM-URL-ENCODED

 Request Body :
 "android_ref_id" : "14"
 "token": "1223232"
```

I use Retrofit and i was getting invalid response but when I use Rest Client, API works fine. I also tried Async Task.
This is what I have tried so far. but no luck.

Retrofit Code 1:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("serveVideos/serveVideosToClient.php?show_by=rating&start=1&end=10")
Call<JsonObject> serveVideosToDevice(@Field("android_ref_id") String android_uuid, @Field("token") String token);
```

Retrofit code 2:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("serveVideos/serveVideosToClient.php")
@Headers({"Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
Call<JsonObject> serveVideosToDevice(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options,
                                     @Field("android_ref_id") String 
android_uuid, @Field("token") String token);
```

Retrofit Code 3:

```
  @FormUrlEncoded
  @POST("serveVideos/serveVideosToClient.php")
  Call<JsonObject> serveVideosToDevice(@Query("show_by") String showBy, 
  @Query("start") String start, @Query("end") String end, 
  @Field("android_ref_id") String android_uuid, @Field("token") String 
  token);
```

Async Task code

```
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    URL url = null;
    String response = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    String urlStr = params[0];
    String android_ref_id = params[2].trim();
    String token = params[1].trim();

    String urlParameters = "show_by=rating&start=1&end=10";
    byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    try {
        url = new URL(params[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

        try {
            // wr.write(postData);

            Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
            stringMap.put("android_ref_id", android_ref_id);
            stringMap.put("token", token);

            wr.writeBytes(stringMap.toString());
           // out.print(postData);

            Log.e(Constants.mLogs, "Json : " + stringMap.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        response = readStream(in);
        //readStream(in);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Both codes are not working. What to do in this case.

Comment: can you post what response log you are getting while using retrofit

Comment: I have attached postman request sample. please check.

Answer (score 0):

For the Async Task code. could it be easier just appending the query parameters to the request URL and sending the rest as part of to the body. see below.

```
URL url = null;   
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
String urlStr = params[0];
String android_ref_id = params[2].trim();
String token = params[1].trim();URL url;
String responseStr="";
try {
        url = new URL(urlStr+"?show_by=rating&start=1&end=10");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid url: " + urlStr);
    }
    params.put("android_ref_id", android_ref_id);
    params.put("token", token);
    StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = params.entrySet().iterator();
    // constructs the POST body using the parameters
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, String> param = iterator.next();
        bodyBuilder.append(param.getKey()).append('=')
                   .append(param.getValue());
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            bodyBuilder.append('&');
        }
    }
    String body = bodyBuilder.toString();
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        // post the request
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(body.getBytes());
        out.close();
        // handle the response
        int status = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (status != 200) {
            throw new IOException("Post failed with error code " + status);
        }
        // Get Response
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();
        responseStr = response.toString();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return responseStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Declare**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("serveVideos/serveVideosToClient.php")
Call<JsonObject> serveVideosToDevice(@Query("show_by") String showBy, @Query("start") String start, @Query("end") String end, @Field("android_ref_id") String android_uuid, @Field("token") String token);
```

**Call**

```
serveVideosToDevice("rating", "1", "10" ,"14", "1223232").enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), response.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Comment: same issue, I have attached postman request sample. please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
@FormUrlEncoded //type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
@POST("serveVideos/serveVideosToClient.php") // POST request to url
Call<JsonObject> serveVideosToDevice(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options,// adding query like url?<key>=<value>&<key>=<value>... 
      @Body() RequestBody requestBody);// Json params
```

Where options

```
{
  options.put("show_by", "rating")
  options.put("start", "1")
  options.put("end", "10")
}


class RequestBody{
   @SerializedName("android_ref_id")
   public int refId;
   @SerializedName("token")
   public String token;
}
```

Comment: @Hammad Tariq Stop using `@Field()` you need `@Body()` https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Field.html

Comment: Brother I tried body also, updated my question, can you please check again. and see if you can help me in any way.

Comment: @Hammad Tariq i can see only `@Field()`s in your code example.

Comment: i forgot to post it. but i gave it try.

Comment: I get successCode 200, actually no errror message. but API return status = false. means improper paramters.

Comment: @Hammad Tariq May be you need authorization header?